# Where to see the Sitecore 9 Form Analytics data?

Tags: experience-analytics, sitecore-forms

I have created a Sitecore 9 form.

In that form, I have added three custom submit actions

1. Save to Database (Default).
2. Save to Custom Database
3. CRM API Data posting.

I have posted some data in that form. But I have no idea about where to see the analytics data for the submitted form?

I checked the performance tab in the forms designer but it have no data. please see the image.

[image]

Kindly advise.

Comment: You are seeing data at the correct location, the Performance tab in the right pane of the Sitecore Forms dashboard provides information about how visitors interact with your forms - https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/analyzing-form-performance.html, you are not seeing data here which mean you don't have data in the database. Make sure your Xconnnect, reporting/processing things are working fine. Are you able to see any other reports?

Comment: Yes. Xconnect things are not working because of a certificate issues.

Comment: converting my comments into the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing data at the correct location, the **Performance** tab in the right pane of the Sitecore Forms dashboard provides information about how visitors interact with your forms. You can view form performance on a **form level** and on an **element level**.
For more see the *Analyzing form performance* document - https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/analyzing-form-performance.html

You are not seeing data here which means you don't have data in the database.
Make sure your **XConnnect**, **reporting/processing** things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your xconnect is up and running, configured properly; you should new interactions being generated in xconnect shards. However, forms data is not aggregated so you won’t see any report in sitecore which shows those interactions and visitor actions. If you are triggering some goals or adding value to visits on form submission, you should see that an Experience Analytics reports or Experience Profile.